# Can I create an exam with a timer and corrected automatically?

Tags: exam

I want to create an exam with a timer for students; I mean the student open the pdf file and click a button to start the exam with the timer, and there is a button to finish the exam at any time, and calculate the result automatically.

Comment: This will greatly depend on the abilities of the PDF viewer. Only very few besides Adobe Reader/Acrobat handles stuff like this.

Comment: There is an actively maintained package bundle called [AcroTeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/acrotex) (Adobe Reader only) which does automatic grading.

Comment: (see in particular the `exerquiz` package from this bundle)